# No Recently Viewed Records In Lookup

Tags: lookup, lookup-filter

A custom object **Payment_History__c** has a Lookup field to the standard Order object.

[image: Field in Payment_History__c object]

There is no lookup filter for the field.

[image]

But when I click on the "magnifying glass" icon [image]

I don't see any Recently Viewed Orders in the lookup search window despite the fact they exist and were viewed a few minutes earlier.

[image]

However, if I search by an Order number, it will return that Order.

[image]

I looked everywhere:

[Lookup field filter does not work on record creation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000239898&type=1)

[Considerations for Lookup Filters](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_lookup_filters_notes.htm&type=0)

[Lookup do not show records](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000giARAAY)

But still I cannot figure out why it doesn't return Recently Viewed Orders. I am logged in as System Administrator and there is nothing wrong with sharing settings. There are other lookup fields on the custom object Payment_History__c which work just fine.

Also I checked Setup > Customize > Search > Search Settings and the Number of Search Results Displayed Per Object for Orders is 25, which is more than enough

Comment: If you go to the Order tab, Is "00002354" showing up under "Recent Orders"?

Comment: Yes, it is. Here is a screenshot https://ibb.co/kjq6pv

Comment: Interesting. There's nothing specific about that object that causes that to fail. It works fine in my org.

Comment: Did you create a tab for Payment_History__c obj? If not try to create it first, that might be help.

Comment: Yes, I did. Actually, the tab had been created before I attempted creating Lookup filters. What is more, other fields with lookup filters  on this object work just fine. It's only Order that doesn't work.